# Not able to proxy REST API request to backend server with latest angular-cli server

Tags: node.js, rest, angular, proxy, angular-cli

I am new to Angular 2 and just created project using latest angular-cli (angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
node: 6.7.0) on Windows machine. I was trying to call my back-end server REST API in one of angular service, but it could not route my request from localhost:4200 to localhost:8080/dz/api/...

I read about proxy To backend support in angular-cli document and followed the same steps.  I do have now proxy.conf.json file at package.json file level.

{
  "/rest": {
    "target" : "(http)://localhost:8080/dz/api/v1",
    "secure" : false
  }
}

and I have updated package.json file with
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",

and then on command prompt - npm start

But, when I call the service, it does not send request to back-end server and instead throws error with 404 (not found error - (http)://localhost:4200/rest/home/list).

I would appreciate if someone can help me out here what am I doing wrong here.  Am I missing any other setting?  I am new to Angular 2.

I did use http-proxy-middleware when I was working with angular1.3 and it was working fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an angular expert , but the port mismatch makes me think that somewhere your configuration for proxy it's not entirely correct. Or maybe you have your proxy and real server running on same machine?

Comment: Yes, currently I have both my backend server code(port 8080) and front end code(port 4200) running on same machine.

Comment: Can we see some source code somewhere?